# flickr.photo.search stopped working for TAGS argoument

Tags: javascript, api, flickr

Whatever TAGS I try to use to retrieve, photos I always get this JSON:

```
{ "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": 0, "perpage": 100, "total": 0,
"photo": [

] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

The photos are there, correctly tagged, and the same script worked perfectly till few hours ago.

Any ideas why this happens?